# How can I use more than one docker-compose replicas in Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm quite new to docker-compose and nginx. I'm trying to understand how I can have more than 1 replica under `deploy` attribute in **docker-compose.yml** when using with Nginx as web server.

### **docker-compose.yml** (simplified):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
      - 8081:3000
```

### **nginx.conf** (simplified):

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

As you can see, even though I assign two unique ports in **docker-compose.yml** per replica, Nginx can `proxy_pass` to only one port per `location`. Thus, making the replica with port 8081 useless in above example. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Create two services app1 and app2 - each listening on its own port

Anf then load balance among them in nginx